# terraform backend state file storage using keys instead of AD account

Tags: terraform, azure-storage, azure-storage-account

It appears that Terraform uses Keys for backend state files when persisting to an Azure storage account. I wish to use a single storage account with dedicated folders for different service principals but without cross-folder write access. I am trying to avoid accidental overwrites of the state files by different service principals. But since Terraform is using the keys to update the storage account, every service principal technically has rights to update every file. And the developer would have to take care not to accidentally reference the wrong state file to update. Any thoughts on how to protect against this?

Comment: hello @JakeUT, any update ?? may I know if the issue is resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a SAS token generated for a Container to be used by that service principal only and no other service principals .

I tested with something like below:

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "foo" {
  backend = "azurerm"
  config = {
    storage_account_name = "cloudshellansuman"
    container_name       = "test"
    key                  = "prod.terraform.tfstate"
   sas_token = "sp=racwdl&st=2021-09-28T05:49:01Z&se=2023-04-01T13:49:01Z&sv=2020-08-04&sr=c&sig=O87nHO01sPxxxxxxxxxxxxxsyQGQGLSYzlp6F8%3D"

  }
}
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  use_msi = true
  subscription_id = "948d4068-xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx"
  tenant_id = "72f988bf-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxx"
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "test" {
    name="xterraformtest12345"
    location ="east us"
}
```

[image]

But If I change container name to another container then I can't write as it will error out saying the authentication failed as the SAS token is for `Test` container not `Test1` container.

[image]

For more information on how to generate SAS token for containers and how to set backend azurerm for terraform , please refer the below links:

[Generate shared access signature (SAS) token for containers and blobs with Azure portal. | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/applied-ai-services/form-recognizer/generate-sas-tokens#:%7E:text=%20Generate%20SAS%20tokens%20for%20storage%20containers%20,container%2C%20not%20for%20the%20storage%20account...%20More%20)

[Use Azure storage for Terraform remote state](https://matthewdavis111.com/terraform/terraform-azure-remote-state/)

---

**OR**

You can set the containers authentication method to `azure ad user account`, after assigning `storage blob data contributor/owner` role to the service principal which will use that specific container .

[image]

[image]

Then you can use something like below:

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "foo" {
  backend = "azurerm"
  config = {
    storage_account_name = "cloudshellansuman"
    container_name       = "test1"
    key                  = "prod.terraform.tfstate"
    subscription_id = "b83c1ed3-xxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxx"
    tenant_id = "72f988bf-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxx"
    client_id = "f6a2f33d-xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxx"
    client_secret = "y5L7Q~oiMOoGCxm7fK~xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    use_azuread_auth =true
  }
}

provider "azurerm"{
    subscription_id = "b83c1ed3-xxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxx"
    tenant_id = "72f988bf-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxx"
    client_id = "f6a2f33d-xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxx"
    client_secret = "y5L7Q~oiMOoGCxm7fK~xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    features {}
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "test" {
    name="resourcegroupname"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "example-network"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.test.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.test.location
  address_space       = ["10.254.0.0/16"]
}
```

**Output:**

[image: ![enter image description here]

[image]

If service principal doesn't have Role assigned to it for the container , then it will give error like below:

[image]

**Note:** For the first scenario I have used managed system identity, but the same can be achieved for service principal as well.

Comment: Thanks AnsumanBal-MT! This looks promising. Let me try some tests on this and see if it works to the granularity I am hoping for!

Comment: First solution worked well for my scenario since I have folders. Appears you can generate a SAS token at the folder level too. The second solution would work if I had everything in individual containers which unfortunately is not the design I have. So thanks again for your help!!... :)